# how to check screen reader is running in html5 application

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I want to make my application accessible.

my application want to behave differently while screen reader is on and off

for example : http://jsbin.com/pakiwuqa/6/edit

when screen-reader(jaws) is on  #textContent should be in tabbing after #btn1 or #btn2,

when screen-reader(jaws) is off #textContent should not be in tabbing

**is it possible to test that jaws is on or off using javascript** ?

Comment: No it is not possible to detect assistive technology. This is a bad approach since many users who have mobility impairments do not use a screen reader, or assistive technology. So you are excluding that user base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how a screen reader (SR) is supposed to work, you don't need to put `#textContent` in the tabbing order.

If the SR user is browsing, they will likely read by using the arrow keys, and they will read through all the non-hidden content in source-code order (#textContent, item 1, item 2). This is standard behaviour and useful, if it could not read the content apart from things you can tab to, it wouldn't be much of a reader.

The `role=application` is oddly placed though, as that div does not contain any form controls, and might prevent some screen readers from reading `#textContent`. [Application](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#application) is a region, and should wrap a set of form controls or interactive widgets. When inside a container marked as `application`, the page is supposed to handle key presses.

If the user is filling in a form, the SR will behave more how you are expecting, and they will skip the `#textContent` unless it is marked up as a `<label>`, you use `aria-describedby`, or they use the arrow keys.

Lastly, there isn't a reliable way of detecting assistive technology on the web, and [there are privacy concerns](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=979298) with that approach. It may never be possible, plus when you factor in not everybody who has a disability uses a SR, you find you're better off building an accessible page/application versus hack.